# Sticky div crosses the limit div, instead of stopping when it touches the top of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

My `info-produto-interno-stick` div is going through the blank div `ancoraStiky` I created with width and height instead of just deactivating by touching the top of my blank div. What can it be ?

```
if(window_top > $('.ancoraStiky').offset().top){
    $('.info-produto-interno-stick').removeClass('stickyCarrousel');
}
```

Comment: In order for your question to be answered please make sure to include a reproducible example of your code.

Comment: You'll want to provide some of the HTML and CSS too, so see if that is affecting the top calculation. Have you tried logging the values with the console to make sure they're what you expect?